# sudo command is not working on mac os x

Tags: macos, terminal, command, sudo

When run `sudo` command anywhere in my terminal then I get following error

```
Zafars-MacBook-Pro:etc zafarsaleem$ sudo
sudo: /private/etc/sudoers is mode 0755, should be 0440
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

I followed this [link](http://instantaneousinstances.com/2012/07/fixing-sudo-on-mac-os-x-lion-10-7/) but when I ran `ls -al /` command I got following output for `.` which is not similar to the one in the link but stil I followed the whole tutorial but it didnt work and I am still getting above output after running `sudo` command. How can I fis this issue?

```
drwxr-xr-x    34 root         wheel      1224 Jan 22 07:43 .
```

Comment: Launch Disk Utility and run "Repair Disk Permissions". This is also a question more suited for Apple.SE than Stack Overflow

Comment: Will it automatically fix this or do I need to give some details?

Comment: It should fix it automatically

Comment: @JustSid you beauty. It works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is "sudo: /private/etc/sudoers is mode 0755, should be 0440"
If you know the password for the root, you could enter in the terminal "su root", and then type the password mode can modify /etc/sudoers file as root (chmod 0440 / etc/ sudoers).
Hope it could work.